# Can't get the coordinates from OpenLayers polygon drawing

Tags: openlayers

I'm building an app using Ionic 4 included OpenLayers.
After drawing the polygon, I can see the coordinates on the console.log but I don't have a solution to get these coordinates.

Here is what I tried

```
ngOnInit(){   
    const scope = this;
   this.addInteractions(GeometryType.POLYGON);
   this.source.on('addfeature', function(coord){
    var feature = coord.feature;
   var coords = feature.getGeometry().getType;
  }

    ----

 addInteractions(geoTy) {
  this.map.getInteractions().clear;

  this.draw = new Draw({
  source: this.source,
  type: geoTy
});

this.map.addInteraction(this.draw);
this.snap = new Snap({source: this.source});
this.map.addInteraction(this.snap);

console.log(this.map.getInteractions().get);
 }
```

I haven't added things that are less important for this.

```
Ionic:

Ionic CLI : 5.4.14 (C:\Users\FQDev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 4.11.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
@angular-devkit/schematics : 8.1.3
@angular/cli : 8.1.3
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 2.1.2

Cordova:

Cordova CLI : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : not available
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and
7 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.8.1
native-run : 0.3.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\FQDev\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
NodeJS : v10.15.3 (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm : 6.4.1
OS : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
this.draw.on('drawend', function(e) {
  console.log(e.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
});
```

Comment: Ouff It works fine. Thanks guy. I've spent over 2 days looking for this solution.